# Fitness function

Tags: java, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

Whilst searching on Google about Genetic Algorithms, I came across OneMax Problem, my search showed that this is one of the very first problem that the Genetic Algorithm was applied to. However, I am not exactly sure what is OneMax problem. Can anyone explain.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The goal of One-Max problem is to create a binary string of length `n` where every single gene contains a 1. The fitness function is very simple, you just iterate through your binary string counting all ones. This is what the sum represents in the formula you provided with your post. It is just the number of ones in the binary string. You could also represent the fitness as a percentage, by dividing the number of ones by `n * 0.01`. A higher fitness would have a higher percentage. Eventually you will get a string of `n` ones with a fitness of 100% at some generation.

```
double fitness(List<int> chromosome) {
  int ones = chromosome.stream().filter(g -> g == 1).count();
  return ones / chromosome.size() * 0.01;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using Java 8 streams would make this clearer: `int ones = chromosome.stream().filter(g -> g == 1).count();`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I am not a java dev, so I was not aware of exact wording in terms of combinators. I did edit the snippet.

Comment: @kreide Hi, thanks for the detailed explanation. I have one question, what does chromosome represent? e.g, does it contain random numbers?

Comment: Here each gene of a chromosome containsneither a 0 or a 1. There are `n` genes. Initially each gene is generated randomly, i. e. there is a 50/50 chance for a gene to be created as a 0 or 1. After the init phase you apply genetic operators, such as crossover and mutation in order to create new chromosomes with higher fitness. This way you are getting more and more chromosomes containing high number of ones. Eventually you stop the GA if a chromosome with 100% is created, or after reaching a certain generation.